# Django Filtering Objects

Tags: django

I have here some issue with the Product.objects

```
def say_hello(request):
    queryset = Product.objects.filter(collection__id=1)
    return render(request, ‘hello.html’, {‘name’: ‘Mosh’, ‘products’: list(queryset)})
```

I get the Error:
Unresolved attribute reference ‘objects’ for class ‘Product’.:6

It returns no list on: http://127.0.0.1:8000/playground/hello/

Does somebody know what can be the issue?

Comment: how are you importing the Product? is it a model?

Comment: from store.models import Product

Comment: There is nothing else in your file that is named `Product`?

Comment: No, not in views.py

Comment: Can you provide us with an overview of the model?

Comment: class Product(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    slug = models.SlugField()
    description = models.TextField()
    unit_price = models.DecimalField(max_digits=6, decimal_places=2)
    inventory = models.IntegerField()
    last_update = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)
    collection = models.ForeignKey(Collection, on_delete=models.PROTECT)
    promotions = models.ManyToManyField(Promotion)

Comment: Do you use pycharm?

Comment: don't use slash quotes, use straight quotes:   return render(request, 'hello.html', {'name': 'Mosh', 'products': list(queryset)})

Comment: Yes I use pycharm

Comment: @inquirer I don't get your point the I don't use slash quotes.

Comment: your line looks like this, at least for me: return render(request, ‘hello.html’, {‘name’: ‘Mosh’, ‘products’: list(queryset)})

Comment: Yes, right and what's wrong? Where is the mistake?

Comment: For me, when using on Linux, slash quotes cause an error, but not the same as yours.